# Why are the lights so bright?

Tags: 3d-view

Im having an issue with the lights.

Anybody know how I can turn down thelights?

Here is the .blend [image]

[image: v=tXH_H5wp73s]

Comment: Please show your work in a Blender screen capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the light are no bright at all (you dont have any btw). you are in clipping mode with a yellow world color.

press ALT + B to exit clipping mode and probably return the world base color to its default or something less saturated.